# How to Insert or Update Blob Data using Workbench

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, rest-service

Bascially I'm trying to execute the example given [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) for the upload of Blob Data from Workbench. but on executing I'm getting below error:

message: Unexpected character ('C' (code 67)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:2, column:2]
errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

I'm not sure how to execute it from workbench.

This is what I put in request body:

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="collection"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "allOrNone" : false,
    "records" :
    [
        {
            "attributes" :
            {
                "type" : "Document",
                "binaryPartName": "binaryPart1",
                "binaryPartNameAlias": "Body"
            },
            "Description" : "Marketing Brochure",
            "FolderId" : "005xx000001Svs4AAC",
            "Name" : "Brochure",
            "Type" : "pdf"
        },
        {
            "attributes" :
            {
                "type" : "Document",
                "binaryPartName": "binaryPart2",
                "binaryPartNameAlias": "Body"
            },
            "Description" : "Pricing Overview",
            "FolderId" : "005xx000001Svs4AAC",
            "Name" : "Pricing",
            "Type" : "pdf"
        }
    ]
}

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryPart1"; filename="Brochure.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryPart2"; filename="Pricing.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

After adding only JSON in request body I'm able to create file in sfdc but those files are empty, how to send data?

Comment: What did you set the content type to on your workbench request? Looks like you may have declared JSON data but sent multipart.

Comment: I have added the body which I set

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the `Content-Type` header that the example shows (given to `curl` with the `-H` flag) within Workbench, so that Salesforce knows it's receiving a multipart/form-data request body, rather than pure JSON.

In Workbench, click Headers to access this data entry:

[image]

You need to provide the

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"

header so Salesforce doesn't try to parse the entire body as JSON, which it isn't.